Show that $x^{13}+7x^3-5$ has exactly one positive real root using Intermediate value theorem and Rolle's theorem.
My approach 
Let's check for the interval $(0,+ \infty )$ since the question is about positive real roots.
$f(x)= x^{13}+7x^3-5$ is continuous on $(0,+ \infty )$ 
We have the following limits:
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0^+} \left( x^{13} + 7x^3 - 5 \right) = -5
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = \lim_{x \to +\infty} \left( x^{13} + 7x^3 - 5 \right) = \infty.
$$
Since
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x) < 0 < \lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x),
$$
we can apply the Intermediate Value Theorem, which guarantees that there exists a point $\ a $ , with $ 0 < a < +\infty $, such that $\ f(a) = 0 .$
This means there is at least one real root in $(0, +\infty) $
Now, let's assume there is another point $ b $ in $ (0, +\infty) $ such that $ f(a) = f(b) = 0 $. 
By applying Rolle's Theorem, there must exist a point $ c $ in $ (a, b) $ such that $ f'(c) = 0 $
However,
$$
f'(x) = 13x^{12} + 21x^2
$$
is never equal to zero in $(0,+\infty)$, meaning our initial assumption was incorrect. By contradiction, there is only one real root in $ (0, +\infty) $. 
My teacher said I can't take $\infty$ like that in intermediate value theorem and gave me zero marks. 
Can anyone elaborate on that ? Can't we apply Intermediate value theorem and Rolle's theorem on open interval ?
Edit: my teacher's solution 
We have
$$
f'(x) = x^2 (13x^{10} + 21).
$$
Since $f'(x)$ has no non-zero roots (as $13x^{10} + 21 \neq 0$ for any $x$), we can conclude that by Rolle's Theorem, $f(x)$ can have at most one positive root.
Also, we have
$$
f(0) = -5 \quad \text{and} \quad f(1) = 3.
$$
By the Intermediate Value Theorem, there exists $c \in (0, 1)$ such that $f(c) = 0$. Thus, $f$ has exactly one real positive root.

Well, that's not the standard form of the intermediate value theorem. The result indeed follows, but if you haven't seen this in class, you should add an explanation. Since the limit is infinity, there must be some $x_0>0$ such that $f(x_0)>0$. Then apply the IVT to the interval $[0, x_0]$. (by the way, you don't need to compute the limit at $0$. The function is continuous, so you can just substitute $0$) I wouldn't give $0$ here, but I do take off a few points for lack of explanation.

IVT inherently is only for closed intervals. It requires a little argument to make it work for open intervals. Here is a nice exposition.
